# Angular highlight.js stop working on route transition

Tags: angular, highlight.js

My main app Component loads and inits highlight.js correctly and everything works fine on first load.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as hljs from 'highlight.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    console.log(hljs);
  }
}
```

However when I navigate to another component and then back again, highlight.js doesn't seem to kick in? I have to do a hard-refresh.

The main root Component use the following template to display the syntax highlighted code.

**main.component.html**

```
<pre><code class="js">{{code}}</code></pre>
```

Defined routes:

**app.module.ts**

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'document', component: DocumentComponent }
];
```

Comment: 1. Constructor should contain as little logic as possible. If you can, move it to ngOnInit lifecycle hook. 2. How do you navigate back? With a back button, or programatically?

Comment: I looked at it again. You are highlighting the DOM elements. I don't know how that library works but I would presume that you should call the `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad()` in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Comment: I've tired these already, I navigate back by clicking on the link to take me to the root page.

Comment: The app component gets loaded once, so moving init call to other life-cycle hooks won't fix the routing issue. I ended up moving the init call inside main app NgMoudle to run when it gets loaded.

Comment: It is possible that you are experiencing the same bug that I was. Try to use the navigate method in zone.run method like this: `this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['yourURL']));` Zone is NgZone so `import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';` If you want more information: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18254